# Guy Yollin's QuantStrat I lecture issue

Tags: r, quantstrat, blotter

I've been going through Guy's quantstrat lecture (link below) and after repeatedly attempting to re-execute the code, I'm getting a few initial errors that are preventing most of the subsequent code in the lecture from functioning.

Here is the code (copied from the lecture with very minor re-arrangements):

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)) #added this to delete memory

library(quantstrat)
library(blotter) #added this hoping it would rectify the errors
library(FinancialInstrument) #added this hoping it would rectify the errors

# initialize portfolio, accounts and orders
qs.strategy <- "qsFaber"
initPortf(qs.strategy, 'SPY', initDate = '1997-12-31')
initAcct(qs.strategy, portfolios = qs.strategy, initDate = '1997-12-31', initEq= 1e6)
```

Here are the errors I am getting:

1)

```
> initPortf(qs.strategy, 'SPY', initDate = '1997-12-31')
Error in exists(paste("portfolio", name, sep = "."), envir = .blotter,  : 
object '.blotter' not found
```

2)

```
> initAcct(qs.strategy, portfolios = qs.strategy, initDate = '1997-12-31', initEq= 1e6)
Error in exists(paste("account", name, sep = "."), envir = .blotter, inherits = TRUE) : 
object '.blotter' not found
```

I had to directly download blotter as I am using Windows 64 bit, but despite copying the code from the lecture, I am unsure why I am getting those errors. My search efforts have indicated that a portion of blotter evolved into the FinancialInstrument package, but even after clearing memory and loading FinancialInstruments I am still getting the same error.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

LINK to lecture: http://www.r-programming.org/files/quantstrat-I.pdf

Comment: Seealso: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Installed-quantstrat-along-with-blotter-and-FinancialInstrument-but-seems-I-m-missing-instrument-tt4654469.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sheets by Guy Yollin are excellent learning material, but unfortunately they are somewhat outdated (2011). Many changes have been made to blotter, quantstrat and other packages over the last 2 years, and much of the code in Guy's sheets will no longer run as such.

As far as the quantstrat package is concerned, you may want to take a look at the sheets from the R/Finance 2013 conference in Chicago; you can get a copy at http://www.rinfinance.com/agenda/2013/workshop/Humme+Peterson.pdf.

**UPDATE:** Guy Yollin has updated his slides to the latest quantstrat as of August 2013, they are available here http://www.r-programming.org/papers

Comment: the link that I provided is the last version

Comment: New link to the Humme&Peterson pdf:
http://past.rinfinance.com/agenda/2013/workshop/Humme+Peterson.pdf or https://github.com/R-Finance/quantstrat/blob/master/sandbox/QuantstratWorkshop.pdf

Answer (score 8):

The blotter and quantstrat packages store things in the `.GlobalEnv` (which is one reason they're not on CRAN.)  When you run `rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))`, you are removing things, that those packages expect to be able to find in your workspace.  In order for everything to work, you have to put a couple environments back in your globalenv().  After running these two lines of code, I think your code will work.

```
.blotter <- new.env()
.strategy <- new.env()
```

In the past, FinancialInstrument used to create a `.instrument` environment in the `.GlobalEnv` (and later expect it to exist).  A couple years ago, I changed it so that `.instrument` is now stored in the FinancialInstrument namespace.  Since that change came after Guy's slides, the code is not compatible.  Slides 14-15 should be changed to

```
currency("USD")
getInstrument("USD")
stock("SPY", "USD")
getInstrument("SPY")
```

Or to more closely follow his original code,

```
get("USD", envir=FinancialInstrument:::.instrument)
get("SPY", envir=FinancialInstrument:::.instrument)
```

By storing package level objects in the package's namespace, the user is free to remove everything from the `globalenv()` without breaking any of the package's code.

Comment: I've tried this and I'm afraid it did not fix the problem. After one month trying to get the code to work via various means, I give up.